# Change BottomSheet design in tablet or landscape orientation

Tags: android, master-detail, bottom-sheet

In my android application, I've used BottomSheet to show the details of the selected marker (in a map view).

What I need is to change the design of this layout when it is a tablet or in landscape orientation. I need to change the design to something like Master-Details and show the details on the side panel (master is map view and detail is selected markers detail). I have seen this kind of design in [this application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flightradar24free&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dfr24_apps_page_new).

Sample Image:

[image: Phone]
[image: Phone]
[image: Tablet]

What is the best practice to do something like this? Is using BottomSheet is wrong in the first place? Also if I change the layout design what happens to my activity code (like BottomSheet initialization part)?

P.S: Also, I don't want to lose my data (markers, details and so on) when the orientation change.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, BottomSheet aren't the best practice for your problem.

I recommend you using Fragments :
[Fragment description here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments)

Résumé : You can easily have two views, one design for the landscape and one design for the portrait.

If you have small data, you can save and restore it using onSavedInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState

Comment: thanks for your answer. How can I manage the BottomSheet behavior using fragments? Like sample images, I need 3 states for details fragment. Also, my data is not small (it's about 4K markers info), and it's not possible to fetch it again.

Comment: Your bottomSheet can be outside your fragment. (a layout composed by constrainstLayout parent, frame layout child and your bottomsheet child). You can programtically insert the fragment into the frame layout. To pass data in fragment check internet, there are extra data to communicate.